# convertin NodeList with one element to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert NodeList to an array.
The problem is that when NodeList is one element long.

It will work fine

```
<form name='moj'>
    <input type='number' value='1' name='pp'>
    <input type='number' value='1' name='pp'>
</form>
<script>
    var Nlist = document.forms['moj']['pp'];
    inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(Nlist);

    console.log(Nlist);
    console.log(inputs);
</script>
```

But this one wil not work, howcome?

```
<form name='moj'>
    <input type='number' value='1' name='pp'>
</form>
<script>
    var Nlist = document.forms['moj']['pp'];
    inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(Nlist);

    console.log(Nlist);
    console.log(inputs);
</script>
```

Comment: [<input> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) has no `</input>` tag. it is self closing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.forms` has to contain a HTMLCollection, on which you could make your snippet work. But :

You are accessing the `pp` property of the HTMLCollection returned by `document.forms`. Wether it contains a NodeList or a simple input is not the responsibility of `document.forms`.

Therefore you need to call something (like `querySelectorAll` for example), that ensures to return a NodeList on the content of `document.forms`:

```
var Nlist = document.forms['moj'].querySelectorAll('[name=pp]');
inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(Nlist);

console.log(Nlist);
console.log(inputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your code not working in the second scenario is this: if you have more than one input with the same name (1st scenario), then `document.forms['moj']['pp']` returns an `array`. If you only have one (2nd scenario), it will return that one element, and that's not an array so you can't slice it.

You can check for `Nlist.length`, if it's bigger than 1 you can call `slice`, otherwise `Nlist` is already all you need:

```
var Nlist = document.forms['moj']['pp'];
if (Nlist.length > 1) {
    inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(Nlist);
    console.log(Nlist); // RadioNodeList(2) [input, input, value: ""]
    console.log(inputs); // (2) [input, input]
} elseif (Nlist.length === 1) {
    console.log(Nlist); // Your only <input>
    // if you want to normalize inputs so it's always an array,
    // you can do:
    inputs = [ Nlist ];
} else {
    // No input elements returned by that selector
}
```